# How do I filter a string array (or list) in PowerShell using the 'Match' cmdlet?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to filter CSV files. But the following script is giving an error. How do I specify that I want to run match on each String object?

I tried various combinations, but without result.

```
$FileNames = [System.IO.Directory]::GetFiles("C:\Users\anagre\Desktop")

$FileNames = $FileNames | Where { -match "*.csv"}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The -match operator is both a comparison operator and an array operator, depending on its input object.

If it's a scalar, it returns a boolean. If it's an array, it returns all the elements of the array that match the pattern

```
@($Filenames) -match '*.csv'
```

Use the array syntax to ensure that you still get an array if there's only one filename returned by `Get-ChildItem`. Otherwise, you'll get back `$True` instead of the filename if it matches.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! Because this will always return an array. In the `$f |? {...}` case, the return value would be automatically unboxed.

Answer (score 42):

Try this:

```
$FileNames = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\anagre\Desktop" -Filter *.csv
```

In your above code you didn't use the $PSItem ($_) in your `where` clause, and if you want to use a wildchar you have got to use the `-like` operator:

```
$FileNames|where{$_ -like "*.csv"}
```

or

```
$FileNames|where{$_ -match ".csv"}
```

Comment: Be aware that $PSItem is new to PowerShell v3.

Comment: Can't we use Wildcards in the Match cmdlet??

Comment: -match search fot the pattern anywhere in the input so you dont have to specify *

Answer (score 19):

The simplest (and tidiest) way I found to do this was as follows:

```
$filename.where{$_ -match '.csv'}
```

or to only search within a given column of a hashtable

```
$filename.where{$_.location -match '.csv'}
```

Then get just the bits you need

```
$filename.where{$_.location -match '.csv'} | select User,Filename,Filetype
```

etc