# Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Property' when running Where-object on an array of simple strings

Tags: powershell

I guess I'm overlooking something super obvious here... running this code:

```
$arraytest = @("one", "two", "three")
$arraytest | Where-Object $_ -Like "*hre*" | foreach { Write-Host $_ }
```

Produces "Where-Object: Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Property'. The argument is null or empty." in pwsh.
I don't understand why. I checked Microsoft docs for pwsh arrays, and also the docs for Where-Object, but no luck.
Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14172574/how-do-i-filter-a-string-array-or-list-in-powershell-using-the-match-cmdlet) I replaced the line with:

```
$arraytest | Where {$_ -match "hre"} | foreach { Write-Host $_ }
```

This works. Is there some hidden default parameter I should have referenced in the -Like example? Why does -match work but -like doesn't?

Comment: You have a syntax error on your first example, you're missing the curly braces `{ ... }`, and yes, both examples would've have worked if it weren't for the syntax error

Comment: Thanks @SantiagoSquarzon. That was indeed the problem. The working line is `$arraytest | Where-Object { $_ -Like "*hre*" } | foreach {Write-Host $_}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since PowerShell 3.0, `Where-Object` has two distinct syntaxes you can use - but you can't *mix* them the way you're currently trying.

### ScriptBlock syntax (or *filter script* syntax)

This is the "classic" way of using `Where-Object`, available since PowerShell 2.0 - you supply a scriptblock and `Where-Object` then uses this block as a predicate for each input item.

It automatically binds the input values to `$_` on each iteration so you can do:

```
... |Where {$_ -match "hre"}
# or 
... |Where {$_ -like "*hre*"}
# or 
... |Where {$_.Length -gt 3}
```

As you can see, we have full access to the input value itself via `$_`, as well as any properties the object might have.

### Property syntax

After the release of PowerShell 2.0, many community members started sharing reusable scripts and snippets online, and it became clear that:

- Many people were using the same simple form over and over: `{$_.<propertyName> -<operator> <someValue>}`
- The scriptblock syntax was not immediately intuitive (at least not to anyone who didn't have experience with Perl, from which the `{ $_ }` syntax for anonymous sub routines was largely inspired)

For this reason, `Where-Object` was augmented with a number of parameter sets in version 3.0 that would allow simplification of the most common use case by providing parameters that *look* like operators:

- `Where {$_.Length -match "hre"}` could then be written as `Where Length -match hre`

The only limitation with the new syntax is that *you must supply a target property* to compare against - so you can no longer compare against the intrinsic value of whatever input value would have been bound to `$_` in a filter script.

For this reason, you have to stick with the classic scriptblock-based syntax:

```
$arraytest = @("one", "two", "three")
$arraytest |Where-Object { $_ -like "*hre*" } |ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_ }
```

In summary:

- Property syntax is useful for writing concise filtering statements when you want to evaluate a *specific* property value on the input objects
- ScriptBlock syntax is required whenever you need to refer to the input object itself via `$_`

---

Is there ever a circumstance under which `... | Where-Object $_ -Like "*hre*"` is a valid and meaninfful pipeline expression?

### Yes!

When you're using `Where-Object` in a scope where the property name you're filtering on has already been bound to `$_`:

```
'Length' |ForEach-Object {
    Get-ChildItem -File |Where-Object $_ -gt 1KB
}
```

Comment: Very interesting. I learned something useful from your answer. I thought I missed some sort of intrinsic auto-bound property, but I understand now this doesn't exist. Thank you very much!